# How to know when a client has disconnected in Socket.IO because of connection issues?

Tags: socket.io

I've noticed that with socket.io server, if the client's network times out, then the server never gets the disconnect event. How do I handle disconnect in case the client silently times out? Or do I get the disconnect even after very long time? Can anyone explain what happens  in socket.io server, when client silently disconnects (power plugged, router crashed, network issues, etc.)

Comment: Read about the `socket.io` heartbeat.

Comment: @jfriend00 teheeeeeeeeeenks! 14 symbols